# add extra property type in map typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const x = [{a: 1, b: 2}].map((d: any) => ({...d, c: 'something new'}))
```

how can I make `x` has `c property` on array of object above?

I tried

`const x = ([{a: 1, b: 2}] as any).map((d: <{c: string}>) => ({...d, c: 'something new'}))`
but it doesn't seems it's the right syntax.

Comment: What's wrong with the output you get? The variable `x` will be an array who's zero-th item will have `a`, `b`, and `c` properties.

Comment: It doesn't work because your callback is wrong `(d: any) =>`. Never annotate the parameter type of an inline call back. Ever.

Comment: Write `const x = [{a: 1, b: 2}].map(d => ({...d, c: 'something new'})`. This uses type inference. You get more type information by writing fewer types

Comment: @AluanHaddad https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA2gbwIYC4YEYA0MARjgEwC+AugHQC2GADgBRMAmOGYAngJRIB8MJmmqjWhYDgDkEELQCmUABYBLMAHMYYeQHcp5HjwCwAKFOhIIADbzqVkOqZweQA using any worked. but how to avoid using any?

Comment: what if the original object is unknown? like from an api response? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDAFAbQN4EMBcMCMANDAEZ4BMAvgLoxYR1gCeAlAHQC2WADigCZIAfKgxsxfYsDwByCCA4BTKAAsAlmADmMMAoDu0yixYwA9CeUhdMKCG0hYNmAFcICxkxjgYfAPwBYAChA0EgQABsFNjCQDRQ4FiA

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA2gbwIYC4YEYA0MARjgEwC+AugHQC2GADgBRMAmAlEgHwxNrUDWhYDgDkEELQCmUABYBLMAHMYYKQHdR5duwCwAKAOhIIADZTqpkEqZwUABhrB2QA works perfectly

Comment: by the time you're using `as any` you're not getting much value out of the type system. For an unknown you should still have a good idea of it's shape or at least it's general constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `<>` when specifying an inline type

```
const x = ([{a: 1, b: 2}] as any).map((d: {c: string}) => ({...d, c: 'something new'}))
```

You could type the result like this

```
const x: Array<{a:number; b: number; c:string;}> = [{a: 1, b: 2}].map((d) => ({...d, c: 'something new'}))
```

Or simply let TypeScript figure it out (preferred as @AluanHaddad mentioned)

```
const x = [{a: 1, b: 2}].map((d) => ({...d, c: 'something new'}));
```

Comment: Why  are you casting away the type of the array?

Comment: I am just pointing out the syntax error in the given code

Comment: Then it's not a complete answer because he also wanted to know how to have the property available on the resulting array elements. Also, while you used correct cast syntax, it's not in the same syntactic context as in OP.

Comment: this could be the right solution.

Comment: Much better now. Thanks for looking at feedback. The last approach should be preferred for myriad reasons

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to name and annotate the types you want to figure out what's needed.

```
interface AB {
  a: number
  b: number
}

interface ABC extends AB {
  c: string
}

const x: ABC[]                      // annotate what's expected
  = [{a: 1, b: 2}]                  // input
  .map(
    ab =>                           // inferred type
    ({...ab, c: 'something new'})   // result is shape of ABC (per element)
  )

// Once more, allowing type inference to do the work
// just to show we can be succinct when we want to be
const y = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }].map(ab => ({...ab, c: 'something'}))
//    ^ NB: y is not typed as ABC[], but has the right shape
```

Personally I often like to specify the type on the receiving variable (`const x: ABC[] ...`) because this ensures that the result it the shape we expect (and if we hover over later, will show that type, not something that happens to be the right shape which might be hard to grok).

Comment: One problem here, is that you are not using a type annotation you were using a type assertion and they have different meanings. Type assertions make the code less type safe and should only be used when the compiler can't figure out what the types are. The way you're using them provides a false sense of security

Comment: Thanks, you're correct, its an assertion, you're implying its a type cast.  The purpose is to show that `{a:1, b:1}` is of type AB (`{a: 1, b: 'foo'}` would produce an error).

Comment: Quite so but the problem is that `[{a: 1}] as AB[]` does not produce an error because it's a type assertion not a type annotation. You can't use type assertions to place a type annotation on an expression as they have subtle to drastically different meanings

Comment: Ah yes, I see your point. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Without an annotion on the arrow function, the downside is that one could place additional properties in, so to ensure exactness, its necessary to add annotations to the arrow function, `(ab: AB): ABC => ({...ab, c: 'something'})`.  Maybe that's beyond what the OP was asking.

Comment: That doesn't ensure exact types. It's standard subtype compatibility. You're just repeating the types.